# py2exe mac os x install trouble

Tags: macos, py2exe

I really do not know what's wrong! I tried to install py2exe on my mac but got lots of errors!

Output is here because it's very long: http://pastebin.com/Ls96ythJ

What I need to do? Maybe it's because I'm using Lion? Help me please! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

py2exe is for Windows.  You want [py2app](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html).

Comment: No, I need to build windows exes.

Comment: Then you need to build them on Windows.

Comment: Is there is a way to do it without Windows? Maybe other tools that can be used under mac?

Comment: I don't understand: you're creating Windows executables without ever using Windows?  How do you test them?  There are virtual machine programs you can use on OSX to run Windows.

Comment: I test it with wine or on my friend's computer. I know that the best way is install windows on VM but I want to know if there is solution for building exes on mac.